# Practice to handle possible nullPointerException by restarting Activity

Tags: java, android, firebase, nullpointerexception

I am trying to somehow cover all the `method invocation may produce nullPointerexception` warnings I get in Android Studio.

I have read lots of topics regarding this issue and I came to the conclusion that the best practice to handle the possible exceptions is by checking the object's value.(null or not null).

Even though (theoretically) the object in my example below should never have a null value:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
```

I still get the Android Studio warning that the following line might cause a `NullPointerException`:

```
mCurrentUser = user.getUid();
```

I then thought that there might be an isolated case where the `user` can actually be `null`, this being caused not by the code I wrote. ( a very low possibility: let's say that Firebase would somehow fail retrieving my user).

The next question I asked myself was: **Even though I checked for the user's value, how my code would execute if he would actially be null? Can I give it a default value?**

Well I can't. As giving him a default value would cause a disaster when I try reading database data regarding that actual user.

I tried a work-around by displaying a Toast and restarting the Activity (so that the whole process of retrieving the `user` would be done again)

```
        if( user != null)
    {
         mCurrentUser = user.getUid();
    }
    else{
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext() , "Oops, something went wrong!" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
        finish();
        startActivity(getIntent());
    }
```

But I am pretty afraid that my solution isn't the best practice.
**How should I handle better such events ?**

Comment: Usually in in situations like this you should present a login screen to the user (if you have one). Or offer (via an alert for instance) to repeat an action that failed - it there's a chance that repeated try would be successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, when we are talking about a `NullPointerException` we are talking about an `Exception` and not a warning. This kind of Exception is thrown when an application attempts to use an object reference that has the value of `null`.

Second, you found that the best practice is to "handle" this Exception, which is some kind of true. I think you are not looking to handle the Exception, because in this case you would use a `try-catch block`. What i think you are looking for is to avoid that Exception of happening. That's why you are checking for nullity because the object reference can be either null or either can hold a value.

Even if there might be an isolated case where the user can be actually null, you need to avoid this case. Because this is the single way in which we can verify the actual state of the object, in case of nullity you need to take an action. Because this is about the `FirebaseUser` object, we are talking about authentication. We aren't talking now about the case in which the object has a a value. If the object is null, means that somehow you couldn't get the user. In this case, for user experience i suggest you redirect the user to the login activity.

You can actually store a default value (i.e. in a SharedPreferences) but this is not recomanded because you are looking to use the correct user not a user set by you. So you need to make all that's necessary to get the right one.

As a conclusion, in case of nullity, display a message to the user if don't have a login activity and force him login again, or redirect the user to login activity to actually retry to get the correct user.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is the explanation I actually needed.  And yes, I have a Login Activity to where I can redirect the user. It makes sense. Thank you